# undefined column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I used the below code to get the table below:

```
data.frame(sapply(tdm_df1[, -99], sum))

and                                      928
are                                      967
biliary                                 1756
bladder                                 3248
both                                    4541
calculi                                 2537
cbd                                     1497
corticomedullary                        1484
```

However the dimension of the data frame is 98X1. How can turn the above table into having two columns. Left one as words and the right one as count.

Comment: `tibble::rownames_to_column(data)`

Comment: `cbind(rownames(data),data)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you!!

Comment: you are welcome. Please try to google first. Or otherwise the question will be marked as duplicate

Comment: @Onyambu Sure! Going forward will keep that in mind.